# Excel formula to calculate value every five years based on years of service

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need an Excel formula where .5% is added to an individual's bonus payout every 5 years of service.

Example:  John Doe was hired in 2010, in 2015 he will receive .5% increase every year until he reaches 10yrs of service in which he will then receive 1% each year until he attains 15yrs of service in which he will then receive 1.5%, etc..

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the percentage depending on the year, I created this formula:

```
=ROUNDUP(A1/5,0)/2*A1-(1.25*ROUNDUP(A1/5,0)^2-1.25*ROUNDUP(A1/5,0))
```

<sub>(The cell `A1` represents the year)</sub>

---

Basically this is a function `Y=A*X+B`
`A` is `ROUNDUP(A1/5,0)/2`

Then `B` is expressed as a function `y = a*x^2 + b*x`
`a*x^2` is `1.25*ROUNDUP(A1/5,0)^2`
`b*x` is `-1.25*ROUNDUP(A1/5,0)`

---

The function yields these results:

```
Year    %
----    ----
1       0.5
2       1
3       1.5
4       2
5       2.5
6       3.5
7       4.5
8       5.5
9       6.5
10      7.5
11      9
12      10.5
13      12
14      13.5
15      15
```

---

UPDATE

I've just realised that maybe you wanted results like this:

```
Year    %
----    ----
1       0
2       0
3       0
4       0
5       0
6       0.5
7       1
8       1.5
9       2
10      2.5
11      3.5
12      4.5
13      5.5
14      6.5
15      7.5
```

In this case just the first part of the formula changes. Both of the following options work:

```
=ROUNDDOWN((A1-1)/5,0)/2*A1-(1.25*ROUNDUP(A1/5,0)^2-1.25*ROUNDUP(A1/5,0))
=CEILING(A1/5-1,1)/2*A1-(1.25*ROUNDUP(A1/5,0)^2-1.25*ROUNDUP(A1/5,0))
```